# Change cache config on the fly in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, caching, configuration, redis, cakephp-3.0

Is there a way to change my cache config on the fly?

Specifically, I want to set a different duration for each key that I set, but am unable to figure out how to set 'duration' on fly, so it's just using the default duration I set up in the `config/app.php` file.

In CakePHP 2, it appears you could use `Cache::write('key', $value, $duration);`, but that doesn't appear to be an option in CakePHP 3.

The reason, is that I'm hitting an API that's returning an expiration datetime.  So I want to be able to cache the data and set it's expiration to match the provided expiration datetime.

Comment: Have you tried [`Cache::config()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class)?

Comment: Yes, but it gives a warning that you can't re-configure the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by getting the cache engine associated to your configuration key, then change it's configuration

```
$engine = Cache::engine("default");
$engine->config("duration", "+2 minutes");
```